# Android Twitter Login Failed

Tags: android, twitter, authentication

I have integrated Twitter(twitter4j-core-android-2.2.1.jar) long back in My application . It was working fine. But today only i observed that Login is getting failed while i click on authorize App . Its showing an exception

```
W/System.err(7725): Relevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
W/System.err(7725):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=bb0a5eb5 or
W/System.err(7725):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=1ef4a1e3
W/System.err(7725): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[bb0a5eb5-1ef4a1e3], statusCode=410, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.1}
```

Can any one help me to resolve this ?

Comment: twitter4j-core-android-2.2.1.jar is got depricate. you need to update with 3.0.0

Comment: okay. So 2.2 version will not work in integrated applications

Comment: try adding new lib from [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/)

Comment: yes, simply replacing the library should work http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This api has been deprecated since 15 days before : for more information you can check
 [Twitter announcement](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api)!
 Now just replece your `twitter4j-core-android-2.2.1.jar`  from twitter4j-core-android-4j 3.0.x.jar [download this from here](http://twitter4j.org/en/)!

Comment: Just Replacing old jar with new jar resolved my issue. Thank you all.